# What is 2 layerd circles component in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, components

[image]

What is the 2 layered circles symbol in this circuit? What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s a 2-terminal current source.

Comment: Even has an arrow opposite to the arrow for the resistance...